# Geofence fire enter and exit after delay

Tags: ios, swift, geofencing

Is it possible to set a delay on didEnterRegion and didExitRegion?

The problem is, if I drive through the region, the enter and exit event fires, but I only want the events to fire if I have been there for +10 min.

Example: 
I enter an region and stay for 15 min and the enter event fires.
I drive by the region and the events don't fire.

And lastly I have another issue:
All the events log multiple times, is that normal?

Comment: use  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    // your code here
} . 0.1 can be adjusted as per your requirment

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can tell the system when to fire the event. Instead, you can maintani the resualt of the event. You can schedule a task (by asyncAfter method of DispatchQueue class) when you enter the region and cancel if exit with in 10-15 seconds.

Store the time of the first even to compare in the exit event, and set boolean flag that you turn of if you exit, and check in the scheduled block.